# How to send keystrokes to windows from a ruby app?

Tags: ruby, winapi

I´ve been trying to interact with another app on windows, which doesn´t have any data exchange protocol implemented. So i figured the best way to do this is by fetching data from an app and send it to the other one by sending keystrokes, simulating human interaction.

But i am having such a hard time trying to implement this kind of behavior! Do you know how to do this using Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install the [Ruby-FFI gem](http://github.com/ffi/ffi): `[sudo] gem install ffi`, use it to load `user32.dll`, then bind and call the `keybd_event` method.

Here's an example from the [FFI Github wiki](http://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/windows-examples):

```
require 'ffi'

module Win
  VK_VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE;   VK_VOLUME_UP = 0xAF;   VK_VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD;   
  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2

  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'user32'
  ffi_convention :stdcall

  attach_function :keybd_event, [ :uchar, :uchar, :int, :pointer ], :void

  # simulate pressing the mute key on the keyboard
  keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_MUTE, 0, 0, nil);
  keybd_event(VK_VOLUME_MUTE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, nil);

end
```

Answer (score 1):

keybd_event would work, you could also use jruby to script the java [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class

Comment: i've never played around with java =/ think i am gonna try ffi first.. Thanks a lot anyway! :)